# Set a property back to "NotSet"

Tags: asp.net, web-controls

I noticed that BorderStlye has an explicit None for "Do not show a Border" and a NotSet, which causes the control to revert to its default or CSS style.

I'd like to set the height of a panel to 0 in some cases, but then be able to return it to whatever height is designated in the style sheet, similar to what can be done with BorderStyle.  Can this be done?

Comment: Do you really need to set the Height through ASP.NET? Why not set the CssClass property to control the height implicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Unit.Empty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.unit.empty.aspx):

```
myPanel.Height = Unit.Empty;
```

This will reset the implicit value you set before.

But if you want to hide a Control, there are better ways than setting the height to 0.

```
myPanel.Visible = false;
```

Comment: Good to know about the Unit.Empty. And I must have been having a elder moment:  I mistyped Visible and when it didn't allow it, tried the hard way.